# Adding an exception to DoS protection settings of my router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, denial-of-service

I have a work laptop on which a corporate VPN is automatically activated whenever the laptop uses any Internet connection other than the office's.

Browsing the Internet on this laptop using my home Wi-Fi is borderline impossible, as loading the simplest page is extremely slow and often fails. This doesn't happen with other devices connected to the same Wi-Fi, or on the work laptop when I am at the office.

The security logs of my home router show tons of DoS events coming from IPs of my company, but only when this particular laptop is connected to my home router and its VPN is on. Normally, the VPN can't be disabled, but IT support screwed it up by mistake while they were looking into the issue, so at a point I was able to test my home connection with the VPN off: no DoS events, connection speed fine. It works equally well if instead of my home Wi-Fi I use a mobile hotspot. So, the problem seems to be the combination of corporate VPN plus my home router.

Tinkering with the settings of my router, I noticed that browsing the Internet on the laptop works perfectly fine if untick the "DoS protection" checkbox.

I'm not a network expert by any stretch of the imagination, and I don't know whether disabling DoS protection is a good idea. As it is enabled by default, I'd rather leave it and see if it would be possible to add some sort of exception that would disable DoS protection only for my company's IPs, or something like that.

If something like this is at all possible (and assuming my router offers this option), I imagine I would need to know the company's IP range. What I don't know is if I would need anything else. Would I?

**EDIT:** Here's an example of the DoS events in the logs:

> DoS: Per-source UDP Flood Attack source=[company IP] destination=[my IP].

There's basically one of them every two seconds.

Comment: What kind of events does the "DoS protection" trigger on? I'm really suspecting that it is mostly, if not completely, useless.

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but I have seen many different ones, including e.g. UDP flood, if memory serves. They typically come at an interval of a few seconds. I added an example to my post.

Comment: Is your question really "can I make an exception if my router allows me to make an exception"? That sounds to me like a self-answering question... Yes, if the router would have such an option then it'd most certainly be possible to do

Comment: @YisroelTech not really - the question is, is this possible in principle and what do I need to do it. Given I don't know much about networking, it might not be as straightforward as  "add exception for this IP range" and so it might not be obvious just by looking at the router's settings that this can be done.

Comment: I disagree. This is not a networking question, anything is "technically" possible to be done in programming/hardware. Your question is about a specific type of protection "your router" uses, and of course if they would have a way to bypass it you would see it there (or at the very least you would include your router model for others to check that.) But instead you asked hypothetically about some device that has a certain function, and you want to know if the function would work and how you would use it... And the answer is "however the device tells you to use it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just disable it.

The router on the receiving end has no means to prevent packets from being delivered to it, so this kind of "Flood" protection is only useful if implemented *in front of* the most vulnerable link, and that's not the case here – in most cases it's not your gigabit LAN but your multi-megabit WAN connection that's the issue.

So if you ever find yourself on the receiving end of a typical cheap multi-Gbps DDoS attack, only your ISP's equipment can prevent all those packets from being transmitted over your WAN link; by the time they reach your own home router it is much too late; the link is already at capacity (and the router's potato-grade CPU is unlikely to be capable of handling it anyway).

(Moreover, unwanted packets that don't belong to any established flow would be discarded by your router *anyway,* without any additional protection. All that it does here is rate-limit legitimate UDP streams.)